# Modal Form Init / Re Render

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to implement modal forms in my project.

In the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgmupn), If I click first button (Hello2), type something in input and then close modal. When I click first button again everything stays as is in the first time (because modal page not initialized). 
If I click on the second button (ngOnInit Sample) everything works as I expected.

But if you check `app.component.html` in the second sample nearly most of the code is written in `app.component.html`. I want to use like in the first sample (`<hello2 #hello2Comp  name="{{ name }}"></hello2>`) but expecting to work like second sample. Re init my form in every open/show form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Hello2 model on close button click you are removing only modal-body and so `input1Model`still hold the input you have provided and so it is rendering whenever you are rendering modal body.

But in other case every time `HelloComponent` is initializing and so `input1Model` in `HelloComponent` is also getting initialized.

So if you want to reset in `Hello2Component` just reset that variable in `hideModal()` method as `this.input1Model = null`. In case of form, you can call form initialization block.

Other Approach(as mentioned in comment)
[Edited_link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyidr7)

Comment: I want to initialize `Hello2Component` like `HelloComponent`.I'm not trying to set one input. I have so many input, dropdown, etc. on my form and it is not possible to set all of them to null and setting the value is not enough. As a side effect `form`'s `validation state`'s does not initialize, so I want to `initiliazie` `Hello2Component`.

Comment: You can remove and render the Hello2Component by throw back the closeEvent and use ngAfterViewChecked life hook to show modal. Adding the code in above response

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you